# TypeScript : Colon vs Equal To ( Angular Tutorial )

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular4 and going through the tutorial examples.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

I have the below code in the tutorial.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
    title = 'Tour of Heroes'; // *1
      hero: Hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Windstorm'
    };
  }

export class Hero {
  id: number; // *2
  name: string;
}
```

In the code 2 classes are defined, AppComponent and Hero. I am not able to understand why for member declaration of a class, AppComponent follows the style **property = value** while class Hero uses style ***property : value***

If I change the class AppComponent to the below, the code doesn't work as expected.

```
export class AppComponent { 
    title : 'Tour of Heroes', 
      hero: Hero : {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Windstorm'
    };
  }
```

I would like to know whats the difference between using `:` and using `=` and when what should be used ?

Comment: In `Hero` it's defining *types*, not *values*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Got it. Please put this as the answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Look again at the `AppComponent`:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

The first field definition:

```
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

is assigning a string value. Because that value is a string, TS can *infer* the type. The line is equivalent to:

```
title: string = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

The second field definition

```
hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};
```

is assigning an *object*, which could be `any` type. So here, to get the most out of TS, we should be specific about the kind of thing it will be. It could also be written:

```
hero: { id: number, name: string } = {...};
```

In the `Hero` class, you're *only* setting types, no default values. The pattern is actually the same in both:

```
name[: type][ = value];
```

It's probably worth having a look in the [TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) for more information about types and class definitions.

Answer (score 6):

`:` is used in JSON for value, example:

```
{ name: "name value" };
```

`:` is also used in typescript to define an objects type. For example:

```
myObj: JSON;
```

`=` is used to make an assignment outside of the JSON.

```
myObj: JSON = { name: "name value" }; // meaning myObj has type JSON and is equal to { name: "name value" };
```

The problems in your code:

```
title : 'Tour of Heroes',  <-- Here you are making titles **type** 'Tour of Heroes'
```

I suggest you to read the basic documentation of typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: If I replace that line with  - title : string: 'Tour of Heroes'; also it doesnt work.

Comment: @JamaicaGeek Yes because you are defining `title`s type to be `string` and then you are trying to define `string`s type to `'Tour of Heroes'` it should be `title: string = 'Tour of Heroes'`. This means `title`s type is `string` and I'm assigning this to be `'Tour of Heroes'`.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is kind of interface but instead of implementing it you can use this class as a type:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number; // *2
  name: string;
}

let a: Hero = 'some call to create new hero';
```

It will ensure that the object is a type `<Hero>` anything else will be cause 
 in type error.

Here you can see it is been used as a type to create a new Hero of type Hero:

```
hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export class AppComponent { 
    title = 'Tour of Heroes'; // here you assign a value to var.  
      hero: Hero = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Windstorm'
    };
  }

export class Hero {
  id: number; // <= here you are declaring a var to be a string but without value
  name: string;
}
```

you don't need to declare primitives if you assign there value immediately (number, string, boolean).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

heroes = HEROES; // heroes ***has a*** HEROES

selectedHero : Hero; // selectedHero ***is a*** HERO

Answer (score -1):

Because it's Typescript, not JavaScript. Typescript have that style of variable data type definition. That's the big advantage in TypeScript: Full oop and typesafe variables.