# studying immutable and can't understand what they say

Tags: javascript, typescript, record, immutable.js

I'm studying about record of immutable.js.

but this code almost kill me.

My Question

1. I know [import, export,const] but [type] is what mean.
2. `defaultValues:`,  `makePoint3D:`, `getName(): string`, `setName(name: string): this` what mean. I never seen `:` unless in object or if .

This question is key for my understanding.

please give me advice!

```
import type { RecordFactory, RecordOf } from 'immutable';

// Use RecordFactory<TProps> for defining new Record factory functions.
type Point3DProps = { x: number, y: number, z: number };
const defaultValues: Point3DProps = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };
const makePoint3D: RecordFactory<Point3DProps> = Record(defaultValues);
export makePoint3D;

// Use RecordOf<T> for defining new instances of that Record.
export type Point3D = RecordOf<Point3DProps>;
const some3DPoint: Point3D = makePoint3D({ x: 10, y: 20, z: 30 });
```

```
type PersonProps = {name: string, age: number};
const defaultValues: PersonProps = {name: 'Aristotle', age: 2400};
const PersonRecord = Record(defaultValues);
class Person extends PersonRecord<PersonProps> {
  getName(): string {
    return this.get('name')
  }

  setName(name: string): this {
    return this.set('name', name);
  }
}
```

From https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

Comment: `getName(): string ` , getName() is your method and part after `:` tells about return type. Basically  part after `:` usually denotes about `type` . return type , variable type etc whatever you are using

Comment: this peculiar way is only js ?

Comment: Yes we use in this way in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getName(): string`  , `getName()` is your method and part after `:` tells about return type. Basically part after `:` usually denotes about type . return type , variable type etc whatever you are using

```
getName() : string
{
return "Hi";       
}

getName() : string
{
 let a = 2;
 return a;
}
```

Second method will give `error` because our method return type is `string` and we are returning a `Number`

Sometime we use `:` this in `if` conditions like

```
 isGendeMale : boolean = false;
 var gender : string = isGendeMale ? "Male" : "Female";
```

**Explanation**

`?`  checks the value if condition is `true` , part before `:` will be assigned if `false` part after `:` will be assigned

[Colon vs Equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368152/typescript-colon-vs-equal-to-angular-tutorial)

[Basic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)